# Working with prefixes and Zend_Controller_Router_Route

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

On an existing Zend Framework website with few controllers and no modules I need to add some prefixes to the default routes.

For example, I currently have :

```
/products
/products/id/1
/training
/commonpage
```

I want to add a product line level, without duplicating my controllers in x modules (I'll just request the right product line inside my controllers with `_getParam` ).

So my new paths will be :

```
/line1/products
/line1/products/id/1
/line2/training
/commonpage
```

What I tried so far is this route (located in my Bootstrap file) :

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('productLineRoute', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':line/:controller/:action',
        array('module' => 'default'),
        array('line' => '(' . implode('|', Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->lines) . ')')
    ));
}
```

But without any success (it gives me a 404).
How can I build a single route that match all uri under those conditions :

- The prefix of the uri match a value in my product lines array
- The route is valid only if the controller requested is allowed to be accessed in a "product line way" - by an array containing the names of my controllers for example

## UPDATE

Ok I managed to get really close of what I'm trying to do with this code :

```
protected function _initConstants()
{
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $registry->constants = new Zend_Config( $this->getApplication()->getOption('constants') );
    $uri = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
    $product_line = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '/'));
    if(!empty($product_line) && in_array($product_line, Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->lines->toArray()) &&
       $product_line != Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->lines->get(0)) {
        $registry->product_line = $product_line;
    } elseif(!isset($registry->gamme)) {
        $registry->product_line = Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->lines->get(0);
    }
}

protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $router->addRoute('productLineRoute', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':line/:controller/:action/*',
        array(
            'module' => 'default', 'action' => 'index',
            'line'  => (isset($registry->product_line)) ? $registry->product_line : Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->lines->get(0)
        ),
        array(
            'line'      => '(' . implode('|', Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->lines->toArray()) . ')',
            'controller' => '(' . implode('|', array('products', 'training')) . ')'
        )
    ));
}
```

With that I can access `/line1/products` but not `/line1/commonpage`, which is what I want - so the controller constraint is working great. As you can see I add the product line name in the Zend Registry, so it is saved when I use the URL View Helper in templates (that way I don't have to edit all my templates to add the product line parameter in my helper calls).

The problem I have now is about this helper : it seems that my controller constraint is just get ignored. When I do this in my template:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=> 'commonpage', 'action'=>'index'),null, true) ; ?>">My link</a>
```

I end up with this :

```
<a href="/line1/commonpage">My link</a>
```

So the product line is added, despite of the fact that this is not allowed by the controller constraint of my route.

Comment: One route to rule em all is deprecated. It is not so hard to google few articles why routing in zf2 as zf1 successor changed. Long story short - do for every controller its own route.

Comment: @venca Did you read the updated part of the question?

Comment: @venca And "It is not so hard to google few articles", why being aggressive like that? What's the point? Guess what I just tried "routing zend framework 2 vs zend framework 1" in Google and didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution : I changed the URL Helper to add the controller constraint inside it. If the controller doesn't match the "product lines controllers" array, it force `assemble` to use the default route (not perfect, but it works for me):

```
public function url(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true, $default = false)
    {
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        if(isset($urlOptions['controller']) && !in_array($urlOptions['controller'], array('products', 'training'))) {
            $name = 'default';
        }
        return $router->assemble($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add / modify specific route with ini params file :

```
resources.router.routes.job_en.route               = "/prefix/:request-offer"
resources.router.routes.job_en.defaults.module     = "core"
resources.router.routes.job_en.defaults.controller = "engine"
resources.router.routes.job_en.defaults.action     = "main"
```

where `job_en` is the name of my route and `request-offer` the param name

Comment: It works but what I'm trying to achieve is to have one route to route them all ;) I can of course write one route per controller + action, but I would have to do like 100 routes, and will probably forget some specific routes with parameters. I'm sure there should be a better way to handle prefixes.

Comment: In this case, the simpliest is to use the regexp router `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex`

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex


and in your config file specify type of router:


resources.router.routes.job_en.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"


resources.router.routes.job_en.route = "/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"

Comment: I finally get it work with `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` (see updated question), the problem I have now is with the URL View Helper.